# How to retrieve array data received in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to do some stuff with ajax in my web page. But what is my problem here is, I have one array in my json result. I don't know to retrieve the data inside my array in `jquery`.

Here is my JSON :

```
{"res":{"tname":"my template","process":["software requirement analysis","efrwefgwerg","ergerger","ewrgerger","erwgrewgre"]}}
```

I wan't to get the data inside `"process"`

And what I tried is:

```
var app;
$.each(data.res.process,function(i,data){app='<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'+data[i]+'<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="proclose close" type="button">×</button></li>';
$('#info .processDet').append(app);});
```

This code gives `single` character from specified `index` of that of `index`. I mean, If it is `data[0]` then it gives `s`. And if it is `data[1]` then it gives `f`.

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @ Felix Kling If it is duplicate, Then it is ok, after hours of research I posted this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `data[i]` to `data`

```
var app;
$.each(data.res.process,function(i,data){app='<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'+data+'<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="proclose close" type="button">×</button></li>';
$('#info .processDet').append(app);});
```

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

You can try this also, If you want

```
var app;
$.each(data.res.process,function(i,data){app='<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'+data.res.process[i]+'<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="proclose close" type="button">×</button></li>';
$('#info .processDet').append(app);});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought it will work like that. Now it works like charm. Upvoted+